# Enterprise Architect - domains relationship

Tags: arcgis-10.0, modelling, uml

I am building an ArcGIS model in Enterprise Architect.  I have a couple domains inside.

The problem is: I want to make the following relationship between two of it (domains) that after I import the XML file to ArcGIS I will be able to choose one attribute (from the first domain) and the second one (from the connect-relationship domain) will be filled automatically .

Do you know how to make such relationship (connection)?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a Domain as your first relationship, have you tried using a [Subtype](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005r00000002000000.htm)? By setting a subtype you can [set default values](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//003n0000000p000000#GUID-33F52F91-3626-4F2B-B8AC-5591A7BC86F8) for each field based on the second domain. The only restriction is that the subtype field has to be short integers, but you can alias the values easily enough when you [create the subtype](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Creating_subtypes/005r00000003000000/).

Comment: Yes, I tried with subtypes and it is working but only with range of one subtype-to one domain and i have predefined values which i can choose from. The thing is that after i choose one of this predefined values from range of one subtype i want the next subtypes will fill automatically.

Also i need an advice how to do it from the level of Enterprise Architect, not from ArcGIS (of course i can try to do it first in AG and then to import to EA but my experience shows that this workflow is not always working properly).
Anyway thank's to speak out on the matter.